# Why isn't "script.text = ..." considered unsafe under strict CSP?

Tags: content-security-policy

According to MDN's documentation on [script-src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src), the following are considered "unsafe" and are blocked under strict CSP:

- `eval()`
- `Function()`
- String literals as used in methods like `window.setTimeout("bad()", 0)`
- `window.execScript` (IE < 11 only)

But why is the following not a part of this list? How is it any different than `eval(badCode)`?

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.text = badCode;
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `script-src` will block inline script execution therefore setting a script text or textContent will not work out. To check it out load an html file with the following meta tag:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self'">
```

And try to execute your code again.

Sources:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/?hl=en